# Model-finding: negated quantifiers

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I want to find a model and a countermodel for the following formula:
$¬∀a¬∃b((P(a)∧P(f(b)))→Q(f(f(b))))$

I tried:

- Model 1: $A = \{x, y\}, P^M = \{x,y\}, Q^M = \{x\}, f(b) = b$ which satisfies the formula.
- Model 2: $A = \{x, y\}, P^M = \{x,y\}, Q^M = \{\}, f(b) = b$ which does not satisfy the formula.

I am very unsure about the fact that the formula says $\lnot \forall a$. Is $\lnot \forall a$ false if $\forall a$ holds? Because this would be the case here, but I thought $\lnot \forall = \exists$ and so the formula could be rewritten to $∃a∃b((P(a)∧P(f(b)))→Q(f(f(b))))$.

Can I choose any function for $f$? I mean, can I also say $f(b) = \lnot b$?

Comment: $\neg \forall \phi$ means what you think it means: it's true if the formula $\forall \phi$ is false and false in the other case. It's *not* equivalent to $\exists \phi$, but to $\exists \neg \phi$; $\neg \forall \neg \phi$ is equivalent to $\exists \phi$.

Comment: Okay, so my model is wrong...can you give me a hint for a correct model which satisfies the formula?

Comment: and "$\neg b$" makes no sense. You have to really specify the function $f$ in both cases. Each version of $f$ contains two ordered pairs, $(x, *)$ and $(y, \bullet)$. What are missing values that work, in each case?

Comment: I know but I just wanted to make clear whether I can choose anything for $f$.

Comment: Why does $f$ contain two ordered pairs? I thought the arity of $f$ was 1 ($f$ has 1 paremeter).

Comment: A function $f$ is generally defined to be a set of ordered pairs$\langle x, y\rangle$, where the first coordinate is the *argument* and the second coordinate is the *value for that argument*. So a function whose domain is $\{b\}$ and whose image is the same set ($f(b) = b$), for instance, could be defined as $\{\langle b, b \rangle\}$.

Comment: It's more common practice to use "$x$" and "$y$" for variables and "$a$" and "$b$" for terms or more concrete things like the members of $A$. Your sets $A$ have two elements, the function contains an ordered pair for each, as I said above.

Comment: Anyway, both your model and countermodel work. Notice that, since your formula *is* of the type $\neg \forall \neg$, it's ok to work with the equivalent form $\exists$, which is what you did.

Comment: The hard thing is the implication because it is only false if $T \implies F$...I could say $f(x) = y$ and $f(y) = x$ which means $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$....

Comment: @Nagase so you say that $\lnot \forall a \lnot \exists b (\phi)$ is the same as $\exists a \exists b (\phi)$ and is therefore also true if it will evaluate to true for **all** $a$?

Comment: I'm saying that $\neg \forall a \neg\exists b \phi $ is equivalent $\exists a \exists b \phi$, and therefore is true if there is some $x$ such that $\exists b \phi$ is satisfied by $x$.

Comment: ...no matter how much $a$ are true. Thanks!!!!! Now this is clear.